# Comparing String and HASH_HMACH in PHP

Tags: php, hash, hmac

I want to hash a value in database by using *hash_hmac()*:

```
$token = HASH_HMAC('SHA256',$value,"mykey")
```

Now I want to select data from database BUT before that I want to compare both hashed and original values.

```
"SELECT * WHERE mytable WHERE item_id = ?"
```

Now, how can I compare hashed value and original value in database to check if both of them are correct in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For comparing the value with the database value you have two options,first you can fetch the data and then convert the string into the desired hash and then compare both of them,secondly directly store the hash value in the database and then directly compare it after fetching.